# How to generate a V11 Spikey？

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

I'm trying to 3D print a v11 spikey for fun  and I would like to demonstrate the surface paintings through carving the surface of the original hyperbolic dodecahedron whose generation method could be found [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5700/).

In order to do this, I need to know how to generate the surface painting of V11 spikey. Are there anyone who knows how to generate this or are there anywhere I can find the way to generate it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm relatively confident those sharp spikes would provide a... "challenge" to print, especially without home 3D printers.

Comment: @kirma yup, they are relatively hard to paint, but after a bit of smoothing I guess It is possible?

Comment: @kirma actually I've already printed it out~ I would post an answer soon~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I contacted Michael Trott, and according to his reply, /i came to know that the so-called texture is not a simple 2D picture wrapped onto the surface, but rather a 3D version. The Mathematica 11 Spikey is consisted of different hyperbolic dodecahedrons with different colors and opacity. And so, there is no way of 3D printing it, you have to color it afterwards.[image: the reply of the author]

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HyperbolizationOfADodecahedron/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information! really helpful~