# Reading the color from a photo of a 3D object

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

While trying to cope with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171023/how-to-generate-a-v11-spikey/171472#171472) problem, it came to me that I have no way of coloring the spikey correctly if I can't get to know the colors. The shapes could be easily judged, but the color gets confused with the rendering process of the 3D object. [image] This is the only image I can get for the spikey, so I wanted to find out how can I get the correct colors for each layer of it with this?